# The necessity of handleSelfMsg in BaseWaveApplLayer

Tags: veins

I thought the handleSelfMsg in BaseWaveApplLayeris is same to tictoc self message which means a node sends message to itself but it looks not.

So what is the necessity of handleSelfMsg in BaseWaveApplLayer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name is indicating, the [method](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.cc#L237) handles any messages which a node sent to itself. Those "messages" are simple events in the sense of a DES and not of a networking message. Then a certain action is taken corresponding to the received self-message's type.

Here, this is either sending of a simple beacon message ([BasicSafetyMessage](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/messages/BasicSafetyMessage.msg)) or of a service advertisement ([WaveServiceAdvertisment](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.6/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveServiceAdvertisement.msg)) (both of them are actual network messages) and scheduling of an event (self-message) for sending the next message (network) after a certain interval.

Comment: so if a node sent message and message lost , self message will resend message by scheduling of an event (self-message)?

Comment: I think it is important to clearly differentiate between when the term "message" refers to 1) what OMNeT++ calls events that are handled by its various modules and 2) the content of simulated frames. HandleSelfMessage refers to (1).

Comment: I added this to the original post